# Python Char Comparisons

Tags: python, string, char

So, I have been working in some problems that require that the code organize a string in alphabetical order, so my first thoughts were to try using char comparisons.
If charA < charB and all that, but couldn't make it. But I guess I don't really know how the char comparison Works.

Need a simple explanation on how they work.
Thank you!

Comment: try out `ord()` and `chr()`

Comment: If `charA` and `charB` are actually characters (that is, length-1 strings), then `charA < charB` iff `ord(charA) < ord(charB)`. That is, if the Unicode code point of charA is a smaller number than the Unicode code point of charB, it's a smaller character.

Comment: In short: each character has an ASCII value. The ASCII values of the characters are compared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you compare chars, their ordinal values are compared

So `'a' < 'b'` just means `ord('a') < ord('b')`

Answer (score 1):

If `charA` and `charB` are actually characters (that is, length-1 strings), then `charA < charB` iff [`ord(charA) < ord(charB)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord).

That is, if the [Unicode code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) of charA is a smaller number than the Unicode code point of charB, it's a smaller character.

Notice that this means that `'Z' < 'a'`, because in Unicode, all of the capital letters A-Z come before the lowercase letters a-z:

```
>>> ord('A')
65
>>> ord('Z')
90
>>> ord('a')
97
>>> 90 < 97 # of course
True
>>> 'Z' < 'a' # possibly surprising
True
```

---

If you want some kind of "friendly" comparison, you have to ask for it explicitly.

Often, you just want [`casefold`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.casefold), which aggressively gets rid of case information, so that, e.g., `A` and `a` can be treated the same:

```
>>> 'A'.casefold()
'a'
>>> 'Z'.casefold() < 'a'.casefold()
False
```

For full generality, you probably want something like the [Unicode Collation Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_collation_algorithm). But Python doesn't come with that built in, so you'd need a third-party library like [`pyuca`](https://github.com/jtauber/pyuca).